# Ubuntu 17.04- E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dpkg, 17.04

Whenever i try to purge mongodb-org or any dependency then I am receive this error

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java7-set-default:
 oracle-java7-set-default depends on oracle-java7-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java7-installer is not configured yet.    
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java7-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fER9.png)

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can we see the exact command(s) ran with `dpkg`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `mongodb-org`. The problem is with `oracle jdk`

Try purging the `oracle-java7` packages

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default
```

If you get any error in above command than try `remove` instead of purge.

Don't install `oracle-jdk` they are not officially supported by the ubuntu repo, so things get broken many times. Try `openjdk` instead.